# Java SimpleDateFormat gives parse error

Tags: java, date

I am doing the following

> SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
>             calendar.setTime(formatter.parse("01/26/2012");

When I do

> calendar.getTime()

I see

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/26/2012"

What is am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: your format is 'MM-dd-yyyy' but you are passing the date string with '/' instead of '-'. either change your formatter to MM/dd/yyyy OR change your date to "01-26-2012"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erm, you give the pattern

```
MM-dd-yyyy
```

to `SimpleDateFormat` then offer it

```
01/26/2012
```

to parse. That's not the format you specified, and it's telling you it can't parse it.

You would need:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

You've set the format to
    MM-dd-yyyy 
And the you expect it to parse the string on a format: MM/dd/yyyy

Try

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```